# How to prevent php script from returning a return code on warnings?

Tags: php, suppress-warnings

### php 7.4.14 on Windows

I'm modifying a script that is launched from a batch file. After the script I test for **errorlevel 1** and jump over code that deletes files, since I want to process those files later but leave them if there was any kind of error.

I'm getting `SYSTEM WARNING: 'Creating default object from empty value' in blahblah line 1333` that I can't resolve because I'm not a php coder and lack the knowledge on why I'm getting the warning and what to do about it. That line of code is `return( $t_project_name );`

So instead I'm trying to just suppress warnings. I added `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` at the top of the script and that prevents the *TEXT* of the warning from being displayed, but internally the script is still setting a return code *value* because the batch file still triggers on the errorlevel test.

How can I always return a **0** for all warnings in my script?

Comment: The generation of a warning message does not directly affect the script's exit code. You probably need to look for an explicit reference to either the [`exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) or `die` keywords, which take an optional argument for the exit code.

Comment: By replacing the actual error with `blahblah` you are not helping yourself o anyone who is willing to try and help you... Also, Please take the [tour]. See also [ask] and in your Question add a [mre]

Comment: Anyone who has seen a php error in the log file would know that the blahblah is the full path to the script name and gives no useful information. I certainly could have added some silly code to represent that but it isn't necessary to the problem. The comment above is most useful and probably the correct answer, to wit: search for a die or exit and see if it is returning an explicit exit code.